# Exception handling in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, error-handling

I have been researching on the proper way of handling exceptions in Apache Spark jobs. I have read through different questions in Stackoverflow but I still haven't got to a conclusion. From my point of view there are three ways of handling exceptions:

1. Try catch/block surrounding the lambda function that is going to perform the computation. This is tricky because the block will have to be placed surrounding the code that triggers the lazy computation. If an error happens then I assume there won't be any RDD to work with (Taken from [this](http://blog.rcard.in/big-data/apache-spark/scala/programming/2016/09/25/try-again-apache-spark.html) blog entry)

   ```
    val lines: RDD[String] = sc.textFile("large_file.txt")
    val tokens = 
    lines.flatMap(_ split " ")
       .map(s => s(10))
    try {
       // This try-catch block catch all the exceptions thrown by the 
       // preceding transformations. 
       tokens.saveAsTextFile("/some/output/file.txt")
    } catch {
      case e : StringIndexOutOfBoundsException => 
      // Doing something in response of the exception
    }
   ```
2. Try catch/block inside the lambda function: This implies deciding on the correct output of a caught exception inside the lambda function.

   ```
   rdd.map({
    Try(fn) match{
        case Success: _
        case Failure:<<Record with error flag>>
    }).filter(record.errorflag==null)
   ```
3. Let the exception propagate. The task will fail and the Spark framework will relaunch the task again. This works when the error is caused by reasons outside the code scope. e.g. (memory leak, connection to another service lost momentarily.)

What's the correct way of handling exceptions?. I guess it depends on what you want to achieve with the RDD operation. If an error in one of the RDD records means that the output is not valid then option 1 is the way to go. If we expect some of the records to fail, we go for option 2. Option 3 does not even need to make a choice as it is the normal behaviour of the platform.

Comment: Question of style I suspect. Not really a definitive answer.

Comment: I am using option 2, but with `flatmap` instead of `map`, dropping (and logging) the errornous rows directly within in the lambda function

Answer (score 0):

In the past we did not bother with try/catch approach except for input parameter checking.

For the rest we just relied on checking the return code as in:

```
spark-submit --master yarn ... bla bla
ret_val=$?  
...
```

Why? As you need to correct something in general and we needed to then start over again. It's hard to dynamically correct certain things. Your scheduling tool can pick this up as well, Rundeck, Airflow...et al.

More advanced restart options are possible but simply get convoluted, but could be done. As you allude to in option 2. Never seen that done though.